# "Few" or "a few" particles when referring to sensitivity of an instrument to faint traces

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is the use of "few" correct in the following sentence? Or do I have to use "a few"? The meaning of "few" in this context is a *positive* one (i.e., the resolution is so good, we can resolve/measure a few ions which was not possible up to now)

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of few ions inside the material.

Comment: The sentence would sound better (and be more positive) if you omitted "*few*" altogether.

Comment: I am afraid that this is not possible as I want to highlight the "few". Before it has been possible to sense ions, but only a large number of them at once. Now we can track few of them at a time.

Comment: 'This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of even small numbers of ions inside the material.'

Comment: You should update your question to clarify that you used to be able to detect ions and the breakthrough is you can now identify small groups/amounts of ions.

Comment: If you're intent on "few" then "just a few"/"even a few" would be better, but it's still not the best option in this case.

Comment: use some instead of few.

Comment: Few v. a Few is, imho, a question for SE English Language Learners, where it must have been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to emphasise the small number of ions, but in a positive way. ***Few***, however, has a negative connotation (as if the speaker wished there were *more*). About the difference between ***few*** and ***a few***, [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/The-Difference-Between-Few-and-A-Few-) says:

> The difference in meaning is subtle, but usually ***few*** *puts a little more attention on the negative*—that ***there is not a large number*** (of people or things). ***A few*** *puts a little more attention on the positive*—that ***there is a small number*** (of people or things).

[Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-few-and-a-few) gives a more concrete distinction, saying:

> When you use ***few*** without `*a*', you are emphasizing that there are only a small number of people or things of a particular kind. So, for example, if you say
>
> > I have ***a few*** friends,
>
> you are simply saying that you have some friends. However, if you say
>
> > I have ***few*** friends,
>
> you are saying that you do not have enough friends and are lonely.

Quoting CaGEL, [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/07/few.html) explains:

> The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language describes “few” as an approximate negator... An approximate negator, write the authors, Geoffrey K. Pullum and Rodney Huddleston,
>
> > merely approximates to zero—it is located toward the bottom of the scale, in the area that contains zero.

---

In your sentence, it may help to insert ***only*** before ***few***, in order to express the advantage of a small number of ions as opposed to a large number that could be observed before.

I would reformulate your sentence as:

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of ***only few*** ions inside the material.

However, it is not clear that ***only few*** expresses advantage. It can be easily interpreted in the opposite way. Since this is a scientific context, I agree with @Edwin that it is much more accurate and clear to say:

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of even ***small/lesser numbers of ions*** inside the material.

Comment: I disagree that "few" in general is negative or implies that you wish there were more. For example: "Few actually hold such fringe and discredited beliefs" or "Thankfully, few patients experienced severe side effects" or "We have few complaints about the situation." It only has to do with emphasizing the presence of a small number ("a few") or the absence of a large number ("few").

Answer (score 2):

Neither *few* nor *a few* is right for your context. It’s hard to know from your description, but you might want a word like *distinct* ions or *isolated* ions or *discrete* ions or *individual* ions.

> **distinct**: Separate or apart so as to be capable of being distinguished, or as being different; not confounded with each other,
> or with something else.
>
> **isolated**: Placed or standing apart or alone; detached or separate from other things or persons; unconnected with anything else;
> solitary.
>
> **discrete**: Separate; detached from others; individually distinct. Opposed to continuous.
>
> **individual**: Of, relating to, or characteristic of a single person, organism, or thing, or one particular member of a class or group.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

With a more detailed description of your sensing method and what’s being observed, perhaps a better word will emerge.

Answer (score 1):

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of few ions inside the material.

This version gives me the feeling that there are not many ions you can detect (in other words, there are a lot of (types of) ions that you cannot detect.

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of a few ions inside the material.

This seems to indicate a few ions get detected and many escape detection. Also not what I think you want to convey.

If you want to draw attention to the accuracy / high resolution of your solution, I would go for an alternative wording, such as

> This sensing method provides an opportunity for real-time observation of *very small numbers of* ions inside the material.